# Links will not open to new window in Carto?

Tags: carto, popup, google-street-view

I would like to have my links open in new windows in CartoDB which I thought I had achieved successfully in the past using the following HTML in the infowindow.

```
<a href="{{sview2}}" target="_blank">STREET VIEW</a>
```

This code no longer seems to work on my new maps and even my old maps. Has anyone else encountered this? What HTML do you use to open in new tabs, windows, etc.

I've noticed that when just adding the url field by itself with no HTML formatting it will work in CartoDB editor (even opening in a new window) but is no longer recognized as a URL once embedded.

Below is a sample google street view I would be linking to:

https://www.google.com/maps?q&layer=c&cbll=40.7307132,-75.313928,&cbp=11,0,0,0,0

Comment: I found that adding an unbreakable space after the target preserved the target from getting stripped once the map is embedded. See revised code:      <a href="{{sview2}}" target="_blank"& nbsp;>STREET VIEW</a>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a known bug due to some recent changes on the cartodb.js library, it should be solved by now. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Is this still a bug? I am having some trouble with doing the same. Thanks